# Correcting relationship errors in tables, one to many, many to many

Tags: mysql, sql, datatables, foreign-keys, relational-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfzTh.png)I am creating a DB for a lawn care business Clients, Jobs, Expenses, Payments. I am having problems with the design of this DB, PK-FK issues. Having hard time wrapping my head around the One to many, Many to Many. Im pretty sure I need a Client and Address table with the Address table with foreign key from Client Table linked so One client can have mutiple addresses etc.

I used examples from multiple web sites that cover relational db management.

Client Table  (Clients have multiple addresses, this is throwing me off! Do I need a seperate Address table for this application?)
PK-Client ID(Clients can have multiple addresses, payments, jobs,expenses)
     ClientName
     Address
     Phone #
     E-Mail

Payments Table
PK-Payment ID
     Client ID,
     Job ID,
     Expense ID,
     Dates Paid,
     Payment Amount
     Comments,

Expense Table
PK-Expense ID
     Client ID,
     Job ID,
     Payment ID,
     Expense Amount,
     Expense Description,

Jobs Table
PK-Job ID
     Client ID,
     Expense ID,
     Payment ID,
     Date   (work completed),
     StartTime,
     EndTime,
     Mow Completed (Y/N Booleen),
     Mow $ amount (decimal),
     Hourly Work (Y/N Booleen),
     Hours Worked,
     Hourly $ Amount,
     Description,

I expect that when I enter in multiple addresses for ONE client that I will get a new Client ID for each NEW address I add in for them. Same for payments, jobs etc. I want each Client to have a Unique ID, that can be linked to multiple addresses, jobs, payments ETC. I feel like I am close... Just would love to have a trained eye to take a look! Greatly Appreciate it!

Comment: why does one client have multiple addresses? Are the addresses different types? (billing address, shipping address, home address). If they're the same type (the address where the lawn is cut) is the reason you have multiple is because Mr Smith has 20 houses and you want to cut all of them? Should Mr Smith have a billing address that is different to any of these addresses (hence you also have a type of address - job address vs billing address)?

Comment: Ok, So lets say Mr. Smith has 20 houses, but there 10 addresses under M.SProperties, billed to M.SProerties. 5 addresses under J.CProperties billed to J.CProperties, 5 addresses under Mr.Smith name and billed to Mr. Smith. All physical addresses. So Client-> single or multiple addresses. So two tables? One ClientID one AddressID, and on the Address table AddressID-PK and ClientID-FK? Address, Zip?

Comment: In that particular case I would record three billing clients (I'm not sure why you'd want to bill mr smith directly when working on a house manages by MS Properties even if it is my smith's company). I'd have a table for addresses, I'd have the client table have an addressid column, and I'd have eg job table have an addressid too, I'd record the billing address and the site address in addresses and then put their relevant ids in client.addressid and job.addressid.

Comment: If you really want to record that mr smith owns msproperties and jcproperties perhaps you can have a parentclientid column that is null (or equal to the id column) for mrsmith, and set to mrsmith's id for mspropeties and Jcproperties - thus establishing a hierarchy of ownership/relationship for clients. Each client can still have its own billing address or if a client.billingaddressid is null you can travel up the hierarchy finding one that isn't null and bill that

Answer (score 0):

In addition/repetition of the comments, I'd have:

```
## Clients
ClientID
ParentClientID references Clients.ClientID
BillingAddressID references Addresses.AddressID
ContactAddressID references Addresses.AddressID

## Sites
SiteID
ClientID references Clients.ClientID
SiteAddressID references Addresses.AddressID
SiteManagerAddressID references Addresses.AddressId

## Addresses
AddressID

## Chargeables
SiteID references Sites.SiteID

## Payments
ClientID references Clients.ClientID
```

Because mowing is a repetitive thing, the site table entry would record the site mowed, the start and end month of mowing in any year and the frequency. The chargeables table can act like a history of all chargeable events occurring at that site, including every time it is mowed (so if you skip a week you don't charge for it and don't write a chargeable) and extras like weed clearing, gutter cleaning, drain digging, hedge cutting etc as one offs. If hedge cutting was a regular thing occurring I'd probably recommend the end user put another site in (can be same addressid) for hedge trimming especially if it was on a different periodic cycle to mowing. It might hence be better to call the site table Job if it is more about the jobs that take place at a site than being about the site itself. 
If mows are incomplete, multiple chargeable entries reflecting the dates attended for mowing, can be made - it may not be important to record that mowing was unfinished but if it is, perhaps a chargeable entry with no/future date as a "booked in task"? The state of someone's account can be derived from summing all the chargeables and all the payments

You might toss most this out, but the core recommendations here are:

- have an addresses table
- have many other tables have an XAddressID column where X is the purpose of the address
- you can even have multiple addresses per client/site/whatever, but give them all a defined purpose.. you could make this totally free form but it adds unnecessary complexity. Just get a list of all the kinds of address you'll need to track for each entity and make XAddressID for them
- sites are owned by clients and have addresses where mowing takes place, clients have addresses where bills are sent
- clients might exist in a hierarchy and billing might take place at different hierarchy levels to site work, having the client table self refer and having billingaddress null or not allows you to track where to bill for a particular client. A business rule of "if billing address null, go up hierarchy until non null encountered" can allow leaf hierarchy levels to have their own billing addresses even if nodes closer to the root don't have one and are billed to the parent

Re the complexity of address freeforming I spoke about, you really could have a Client, Address and ClientAddress (3 columns, addresstype, clientid and addressid) tables and allow the client to have any kind of address at all, just by putting "billing", "emergency contact", "correspondence", "managing director's home", "ceo's mother" or whatever in the type column.. but then there are two important things to consider:

- people don't want that much choice; it's a headache for them and a headache for you:
- if you have some programmatic reliance on certain types of addresses (emergency contact, billing) you're going to have to code up business rules to check that every client has these two address types on record, especially if the field is totally free form.

The UI gets more complex as you have to provide a pick list of multiple addresses etc

"Go for the simple solution, not the perfect one"